# Converting .NET Web API Token to 6 digits number OTP

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, token, webapi

How do I convert the following token to 6 digit number and vice versa.

> Hash/Encrypt

Q3XMaFgx3l0n9Nkb8XIUTZ9jqWDOJtefhPtv0yXPQhFBUq_hhGyW9p54apIDTpFs5Am_6Rs8VSKLClDJjFfOtM78I8EDLjwd4zjvWK0WBN9g7I2_F2D9uxEWfSUrgIIzAqw2jqGkOweW7avOmdtAdaTzlqtAY1eXJfgZg1JrkWmr9oqxsEeedViYMrJgGLssIGJM_pjTEnlwsmQiVdH5wJWwDgj5No8Wt7YdsV1sKs_44rrjfavhI4tez0vbMoeWAj5sXqTaVGH4AeVLrIUkyN7XsNJhBFTOEWyqC3L5uOXkqT_KRXOF6DV0fdMIfBmUx05hw4A
   `=========>` 123456

> Reverse Hashing/ Decrypt [to get back the original token]

- 123456 `=========>`
  Q3XMaFJu3Kgx3l0n9Nkb8Xu0IUTZ9jqWDOJtefhPtv0yXPQhFBUq_hhGyW9p54apIDTpFs5Am_6Rs8VSKLClDJjFfOtM78I8EDLjwd4zjvWK0WBN9g7I2_F2D9uxEWfSUrgIIzAqw2jqGkOweW7avOmdtAdaTzlqtAY1eXJfgZg1JrkWmr9oqxsEeedViYMrJgGLssIGJM_pjTEnlwsmQiVhdH5wJWwDgj5No8Wt7YdsV1sKs_44rrjfavhI4tez0hvbMoeWAj5sXqTaVGH4AeVLrIUkyN7XsNJhBFTOEWyqC3L5uOXkqT_KRXOF6DV0fdMIfBmUx05hw4A

Comment: No, that's not secure, it decreases your possible password space from somewhere near infinity down to one million, which a hacker can try in mere minutes (granted you've got a somewhat decent web server and no other security measures in place). Sure, you'll then say "But it's in the requirements", but then your requirements are incomplete. Also, no, this is impossible. You can't reverse a hash, and you can't possibly encrypt 300+ alphanumeric characters in 6 digits. So you have an XY problem. What do you actually want to do? And yeah, you've edited this question while I was typing this.

Comment: @CodeCaster Sorry but yes, the requirements was to generate 6 digit numbers and send to mobile numbers and yes no databases should be used. So I thought to make use of ASP.NET web api tokens. Add the user's info in claims and generate token. At first I tried passing the whole token to client and validated. But the requirement was to create 6 digits number. So then I thought just to convert the token to 6 digit number and send to client. Now when I have to validate it, I just reverse the algorithm and get the original token and validate the claims details. If all looks fine,, I return true.

Comment: Yes of course the requirement is to make an insecure system. Because of "convenience". And nobody pushed back on that, because they didn't understand the implications. And if you really want that, you can. But you can **not** squish an authentication token into six digits. So you'll have to have a database, where you use this one-time password as actual password that performs a login for the given user, and _then_ returns a full token.

Comment: @CodeCaster As token are unique, so say if [apitoken] is converted to 123456. And now while validating the 6 digit number i.e 123456, First I convert it to original token. After 2 mints, it will fail as the token will expiry. So the user will have to again generate a new 6 digit number.

Comment: Yes, but the number 123456 is too short to contain both a token and an expiration date. You can explain what you want over and over again, but it is not possible. You have to persist this token you generate somewhere. You **cannot** replace the entire token with a short number in a reversible way, without persisting the original token somewhere. And again, you don't want that (as the token itself is also prone to expiring), you want to generate a token when they log in using their one-time password.

Comment: @CodeCaster the requirement is just to validate the 6 digit number. return true if it matches or false if it doesn't. There is no need to pass any tokens to the client side.

Comment: Yeah and "the requirements", what it always comes down to in questions like this, are mandated and approved by people who don't know what they are doing. You want a one-time password, then implement it as such. You need a database.

Comment: @CodeCaster Okay so I think, if I have to make it secure then first I add users details in claims and generate tokens and also generate 6 digit number using some hash algorithm. Save them both in database. Pass the otp to clients..While validating, check both the OTP and token, if both are valid, check the claims details i.e phone and mail..if all looks fine..return true,..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is actually impossible. Whilst Hash functions can produce an output in a certain range, they cannot be reversed, and encryption (broadly speaking) requires that the cipher text be the same length as the plain text..

Based on the comments, what you need to do is generate a 6 digit number and store it for a very short amount of time to facilitate a login.

You *could* use the [MemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache?view=netframework-4.8) class (Full framework) or [IMemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-3.1) (net core) interface to store the randomly generated number keyed by the user id or email, and check that the value exists and matches the one supplied by the user.

However I would consider the points raised in the comments **very** seriously as there are a great many pitfalls associated with generating "Random" numbers properly, and it may be possible for an attacker to guess the number with far better accuracy than a true random number.

You should consider using an established library for managing SMS 2FA assuming that is really the end goal. A quick google turned up this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/two-factor-authentication-using-sms-and-email-with-aspnet-identity